Ordering by IN clause order
Suppose I want the order of output records match the order in the IN clause
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 1 AS id, 'one' AS text FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, 'two' AS text FROM DUAL
) t WHERE t.id IN (2,1)

Expected:



id
text




2
two


1
one



Actual:



id
text




1
one


2
two



Obviously, I can't hardcode it like this (GPT's suggestion). Ids and their order are dynamic
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'one' AS text FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'two' AS text FROM DUAL
) t 
WHERE t.id IN (2, 1)
ORDER BY CASE t.id
  WHEN 2 THEN 1
  WHEN 1 THEN 2
END;

How do I do it?
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production (bonus points if it works for PostgreSQL as well)


Ids and their order are dynamic

In that case, I don't think that you can do it in pure SQL.
Simple test case you posted is really simple. Those values could've been e.g. in (18, 2, 5, 38) so ... without manually typed CASE expression, how will you sort rows in that order?
But: if you're creating the in list dynamically (how exactly?), can't you pre-sort those values within the in list (so that you'd actually get in (2, 5, 18, 38) and then simply order by id?
Or, create a function which creates the whole select statement, composing the order by clause as well and then either return the select statement (you'd execute later), or make that function return e.g. ref cursor.

Thank you. Ids are persisted to an XML file, then read at runtime. But imagine they demand it, "Preserve the order"? What should I do then?

Maybe add additional information into the XML file, let's call it SORT_ORDER, which would be incremented for every new row in the file (that should be done by people who create the file). Then you'd pre-process the file, store its contents into a table, join it to the "original" source table you use to extract data and apply order by that_table.sort_order.

You cannot sort by values list, rowset needed:
SELECT t.* 
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id, 'one' AS text FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 2 AS id, 'two' AS text FROM DUAL
       ) t
JOIN ( SELECT 2 id, 1 ordering FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 1, 2
       ) o ON t.id = o.id
ORDER BY o.ordering;

https://dbfiddle.uk/vmhw-8Nl
